# Does Oracle have something like Change Data Capture in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Change Data Capture is a new feature in SQL Server 2008.  From MSDN:

> Change data capture provides
>   historical change information for a
>   user table by capturing both the fact
>   that DML changes were made and the
>   actual data that was changed. Changes
>   are captured by using an asynchronous
>   process that reads the transaction log
>   and has a low impact on the system

This is highly sweet - no more adding CreatedDate and LastModifiedBy columns manually.

Does Oracle have anything like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.  Oracle actually has a number of technologies for this sort of thing depending on the business requirements.

- Oracle has had something called [Workspace Manager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14253/long_intro.htm#ADWSM010) for a long time (8i days) that allows you to version-enable a table and track changes over time.  This can be a bit heavyweight, though, because it is based on views with instead-of triggers.
- Starting in 11.1 (as an extra cost option to the enterprise edition), Oracle has a Total Recall that asynchronously mines the redo logs for data changes that get logged to a separate table which can then be queried using flashback query syntax on the main table.  Total Recall is automatically going to partition and compress the historical data and automatically takes care of purging the data after a specified data retention period.
- Oracle has a LogMiner technology that mines the redo logs and presents transactions to consumers.  There are a number of technologies that are then built on top of LogMiner including [Change Data Capture](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/cdc.htm#sthref889) and [Streams](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14229/strms_over.htm#STRMS001).
- You can also use materialized views and materialized view logs if the goal is to replicate changes.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle has Change Data Notification where you register a query with the system and the resources accessed in that query are tagged to be watched.  Changes to those resources are queued by the system allowing you to run procs against the data.

This is managed using the DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION package.

Here's an infodoc about it:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_change_notification_10gR2.php

If you are connecting to Oracle from a C# app, ODP.Net (Oracles .Net client library) can interact with Change Data Notification to alert your c# app when Oracle changes are made - pretty kewl.  Goodbye to polling repeatedly for data changes if you ask me - just register the table, set up change data notifcation through ODP.Net and wala, c# methods get called only when necessary.  woot!

Answer (score 2):

"no more adding CreatedDate and LastModifiedBy columns manually" ... as long as you can afford to keep complete history of your database online in the redo logs and never want to move the data to a different database.

I would keep adding them and avoid relying on built-in database techniques like that. If you have a need to keep historical status of records then use an audit table or ship everything off to a data warehouse that handles slowly changing dimensions properly.

Having said that, I'll add that Oracle 10g+ can mine the log files simply by using flashback query syntax. Examples here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2112847

This technology is also used in Oracle's Datapump export utility to provide consistent data for multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Oracle has provided auditing features since 8i, however the tables used to capture the data are rather complex and there is a significant performance impact when this is turned on.

In Oracle 8i you could only enable this for an entire database and not a table at a time, however 9i introduced Fine Grained Auditing which provides far more flexibility. This has been expanded upon in 10/11g.

For more information see http://www.oracle.com/technology/deploy/security/database-security/fine-grained-auditing/index.html.

Also in 11g Oracle introduced the Audit Vault, which provides secure storage for audit information, even DBA's cannot change this data (according to Oracle's documentation, I haven't used this feature yet). More info can be found at http://www.oracle.com/technology/deploy/security/database-security/fine-grained-auditing/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has mechanism called Flashback Data Archive. From [A Fresh Look at Auditing Row Changes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2016/16-mar/o26performance-2925662.html):

> Oracle Flashback Query retrieves data as it existed at some time in the past.
>
> Flashback Data Archive provides the ability to track and store all transactional changes to a table over its lifetime. It is no longer necessary to build this intelligence into your application. A Flashback Data Archive is useful for compliance with record stage policies and audit reports.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE SPACE_FOR_ARCHIVE 
datafile 'C:\ORACLE DB12\ARCH_SPACE.DBF'size 50G;

CREATE FLASHBACK ARCHIVE longterm
TABLESPACE space_for_archive
RETENTION 1 YEAR;

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES FLASHBACK ARCHIVE LONGTERM;


select EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, JOB_ID, VACATION_BALANCE,
        VERSIONS_STARTTIME TS,
        nvl(VERSIONS_OPERATION,'I') OP
from EMPLOYEES
versions between timestamp  timestamp '2016-01-11 08:20:00' and systimestamp
where EMPLOYEE_ID = 100
order by EMPLOYEE_ID, ts;
```